# Javascript q promise never call callback

Tags: javascript, q

I am very new to javascript and q promise.

I have the following code:

```
function test(arg1, arg2){
        myobject.callPromiseFunc().then(function(id){
                // Do some stuff
        });
}
```

I run this code using node.js, and it is called using an express `get` request.

The callback code in `then` is never called. However, if I replace the callback code by a `console.log` call, it works.

Do you have any idea why the callback is never called?

Comment: can you share callPromiseFunc also

Comment: it could be throwing an error in callPromiseFunc, try chaining .catch(function (error) {
    // Handle any error from all above steps
})

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*replace the callback code by a console.log call*", `myobject.callPromiseFunc().then(console.log)`?

Comment: So that does work and logs something but `myobject.callPromiseFunc().then(function(id){ console.log(id); // do some more stuff; })` does not? That's hard to believe. Maybe there's a syntax error in the more stuff?

Comment: @Bergi Yes that's exactly the situation, and that's what I do not understand. I have only the following code: `.then(function(id){console.log("success"); });` and nothing is printed in the console.

Comment: That's weird, but unfortunately not reproducible. Can you share your complete code, please?

Comment: @Bergi That would be too complex, as I use others dependencies. But I understand from your comments that my code should work (I thought I used that the wrong way), so it could come from one of these dependency that create the promise. Thanks.